# Mysql new Table

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-security, foreign-keys

I have some doubt in my table

```
    CREATE TABLE user_roles(
    user_role_id int(10) unsigned not null, 
    user_id int(10) unsigned not null, 
    authority varchar(45) not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id), 
    KEY FK_user_roles (user_id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles FOREING KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i get the following error:

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FOREING KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=' at line 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake

FOREIGN not FOREING